# Fabric failed to detect build environment with static libraries

Tags: ios, static-libraries, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

In my project targets i've a static libraries. I'd like to add crashlytics to them. I've add **Run Script**, **Frameworks Search Path**, **Info plist file path** of Crashlytics to my static library build settings. When i build project, i have an issue:

[image]

What i should do to fix this problem. Help me, if this possible.

Comment: did you find a solution for the problem you described? I see that much time passed so I hope so :)